# Save and restore window positions

Tags: 12.04, unity, window

Here is my configuration:

- Ubuntu 12.04 (with Unity)
- Laptop
- External screen to use the laptop in dual screen mode
- Several windows spread on both screens and on 4 workspaces

When I have meetings I unplug the screen from my laptop to take the laptop to the meeting room, so all the windows are re-positioned to fit in one screen only. After the meeting, when I plug it back to the external screen, I need to manually move all the windows back in place.

Is there a way to save and restore the windows, so that I don't have to do this manually everytime? A script with save/restore options would be great!

Thanks!

**Note:** I don't think this is a duplicate of "How do I save sessions or reopen last-used applications?", since I keep my computer turned on (the solution explained in the other post is about using an hibernation tool tweak).

**Note 2:** I found [this script](http://thialfihar.org/projects/window_position_session/), but it does not work.

**Edit (2013-06-03)** the tool `wmctrl` can help to get and set windows positions. I created a Shell script with it, but there is a known [bug in Unity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/971147) which makes it impossible to use there. Even on XFCE the result is random sometimes...